# Click Event to Animate Raphael Path Broken in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, raphael

I have created a Raphael document and am storing the locations like so:

```
  var R = Raphael("paper", 600, 500);
  var attr = {
      fill: "#fff",
      stroke: "#fff",
      "stroke-width": 1,
      "stroke-linejoin": "round"
  };
```

-- get coords from db assigned to `object` 'ausData' and create a `object` 'aus' --

```
$.each(ausData,function(i,obj) {
  attr.fill = myData[i].color;
  aus[i] = R.path(obj).attr(attr);
  aus[i].id = myData[i].id;
  mapIdObj[stateData[i].id] = R.getById(stateData[i].id);//aus[i].id;
});
```

so the path object is stored in the object mapIdObj

I am then attempting to alter the path object by clicking on a link. in the .success of the `jQuery.post.success` I am iterating through all the elements, and appending an anchor tag to the page, and on `jQuery.post.complete` I am attempting to bind a click:

```
$('#superHappyDiv').append('<a id="button'+st.id+'" class="superButton" name="button'+st.id+'" ref="'+st.id+'" class="" href="javascript:;" title="" target="">x</a>');


$('.superButton').live('click onmousedown',function() {
  if (window.console) console.log($(this).attr('ref'));
  var thisPath = mapIdObj[$(this).attr('ref')];
  thisPath.animate({ 'transform': 's2', opacity: .9 }, 300, "<>");
});
```

Other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461716/adding-ids-to-raphael-objects) have pointed to this as working, and it does, but not in IE 7, and 8 at least!

Is there a more efficient way to get this working, or working at all in IE?!

Cheers, Bo

Comment: I think that posting a jsfiddle would help you getting a working answer sooner ... in my case it did :)